# How do I know the location of Python files from ajax on the Django server?

Tags: javascript, ajax, django

I need to send data to Python file with ajax, but I can't find a path, so I get 404 Not Found.

So I tried to put that Python file in every folder and I tried to live it, but the same error occurred.

```
$.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
                url: "test.py",
                data: params,
                dataType: "html",
                success: function (html)
                {
                    alert("success");
                },
                error: function(request, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
                {
                    alert("fail");
                }
            });
```

error message is

```
POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/test.py 404 (NOT FOUND)
```

Do I have to add a path to `urls.py`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to add a path. Your JS doesn't know anything about Python files, it knows about URLs. So you need to add a path in your urls.py that points to a view, and then use that path in your Ajax call.